# Collapsing comments produces misleading information

Tags: discussion, comments, user-interface

I went back to [one of answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10324272/why-is-it-not-a-good-practice-to-synchronize-on-boolean/10324280#10324280) recently and I saw the following comments.

> [image]

The first comment is shown then my response.  Unfortunately, the comments between these two are not shown and provide important context to my "yes @Rachel" statement.   The above looks like I'm agreeing with her which is incorrect.  Although I'm on SO daily, it still tripped me up until I remembered to look for the "show X more comments" link below.

I understand that this is a hard job.  No perfect solutions immediately jump into my mind on how to better pair down the comments, but here are some thoughts for consideration.  Please excuse my ignorance of the full problem at hand.

- Can there be some sort of visual cue that some intervening comments have been hidden?  Maybe a small *<sub>comments hidden</sub>* message or something on the line above?  How about a little + button to the left of the line indicating that something was collapsed?
- Maybe have a little "Partial comments below, click + for all" but at the *top* of the comments?
- Maybe, if some comments are hidden, always show the last comment before the one being shown to try and preserve the context?  I know, I know.  This is not perfect as well and you can still engineer an order to the comments that results in improper context.

I hope that this at least starts a discussion and maybe others can come up with better algorithms around pairing down comments.

For those interested, here's the full thread with the comments.

> [image]

Thanks.  Hope something here helps.

Comment: Somewhat related to: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296582/collapsed-comments

Comment: Hrm.  Should this be moved to meta.stackexchange.com?

Comment: Instead of completely getting rid of the `show more comments...` link, why not make it a bit clearer? Perhaps `show all comments(n)` where `n` is the number of comments? I really don't think the problem requires a complete user interface overhaul.

Comment: If that's the case then I'm afraid I'm going to have to remove my upvote and downvote your question for lack of [hand-drawn circles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/19775#19775). _tsk_, _tsk_ a high reputation user like you really should know  better.

Comment: Down voting because freehand circles are orange, not red

Comment: Problem: comments are hidden based on vote levels. Solution: upvote Rachel's other comment. :-)

Comment: Perhaps there should be a way to reply directly to a specific comment, rather than just to a person.

Comment: I agree with the comment directly above this one.

Comment: Why are we hiding comments to begin with? Okay, if they've been flagged, give a visual que to them that they have been flagged, perhaps, but why hide them? Are we allergic to scrolling a little bit? Comments should be shown in context, and yes, it would be better to have nested comments, but I get why that's not implemented.

Comment: I think they don't want the comments to the answers to bury the answers below @junkfoodjunkie.  There are some _huge_ comment threads that still have value but maybe only when you need more data.  The answers are supposed to be more important.

Comment: So? Have a user-setting to either show or hide comments as default? Or a toggle-button for showing and hiding them, with a cookie or localstorage settings remembering the choice? It's NOT rocket science, but the current hide-function leaves a lot to be desired, since there is no visual indication whatsoever that there might be comments hidden, unless you actually look at the link below.

Comment: I think there's a jQuery plugin for this.

Comment: Solution: delete the comments ;) Or more realistically, move them to the post.